# How should image data from expo-image-picker be sent to Express and Multer Endpoint?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, expo, multer

I am having difficulty with figuring out how to send images to my backend. Essentially, my confusion comes from me not knowing what I need my backend to even look like to match my frontend fetch code. My front end code is below:

```
const onSignUp = () => {
const data = new FormData();
console.log(profilePictureData)
data.append('ProfilePhoto', {
  uri: (Platform.OS === 'android' ? profilePictureData.uri : profilePictureData.uri.replace('file://', '')),
  type: profilePictureData.type,
  name: profilePictureData.fileName
});

const profilePicUrl = `someherokuapi.com/api/photos/profile/me`

fetch(profilePicUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-auth-token': token
  },
  body: data
})
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using multer at your backend.